# Linking Qt on CLion

Tags: c++, qt, clion, jetbrains-ide

After googling a lot, I can't still figure out how to link Qt on CLion and start working on a project with it.

Can someone please explain step-by-step?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

CLion is working with CMake project model, so you need to link your Qt libraries via CMake. Here is [Qt's official documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html) on this.
If you ask about qmake, it's not supported currently in CLion.